# How is $\{a_i\} $ equal to $B(a_i,{1\over2})$ in the discrete metric?

Tags: general-topology

> In a discrete metric space show that a set is compact iff it is finite

While proving $\implies$ direction,

We showed that if A is compact then $\bigcup _{\alpha \in \wedge } B(a,{1\over 2}) $ is an open cover for A.

Then we further showed that it has to have a finite sub cover too (since it is compact), say 
$\bigcup^n _{i=1 } B(a_i,{1\over 2}) $

And we continued by $A \subseteq \bigcup^n _{i=1 } B(a_i,{1\over 2})= \bigcup^n _{i=1 }\{a_i\} $

I don't understand how this equality holds

Comment: Remember that your space consists of points $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ *only* (since it's finite). Since it is a discrete space $a\ne b \Rightarrow d(a,b) = 1$. Hence $B(a_i,\frac 1 2) = \{a_i\}$.

Comment: @ElChorro: The second sentence of your comment is relevant but not the first, to the question asked.  The goal is to *prove* that the space is finite *if* it is compact, not to remember it (i.e. it's not assumed here).

Comment: You are absolutely right! I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that
$$
B(a_i,1/2) = \{a\in A \mid d(a,a_i)<1/2\}.
$$
If $d$ is the discrete metric, then $d(a,a_i)<1/2$ iff $a=a_i$. Thus the above is just $\{a_i\}$.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent explanation, it's so precise! @John Griffin